# Is the database structuration of Magento can be up dated?

Tags: database

**Subject  :** 
I have MySQL Server contains Magento's DataBase (I have the diagram standard of magento) By VBA Excel I developped an application which extract many informations from Magento (By exécuting SQL requests). 
**Question :** 
Is the structuring of magento can be updated ? 
like there is a table called 'sales_flat_invoice' and after updating it will be called 'sales_flat_invoice_V2'

so if it is possible it means my application wont work anymore with old SQL Requests and I have to change the SQL requests in the application :( 
any help please !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IN theory, the table names do not change.
It happened once in 1.4 when the `sales_order` table changed to `sales_flat_order` but this is because the sales entities were drastically changed.
But keep in mind that new tables may appear and new columns in old tables.